# Injeção de JavaScript no Internet Explorer, retorna null

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, null

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que realiza automatização no internet explorer, estou utilizando o [SHDocVw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741313(v=vs.85).aspx) para fazer isto.

Meu problema é que não consigo pegar o retorno de uma injeção de **JavaScript**

```cs
public static void wJScript(string script) {
  try {
    Thread th = new Thread(ExecuteJavaScriptWorker);
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start(script);
  }
  catch (Exception) {
    throw;
  }
}

private static void ExecuteJavaScriptWorker(object script) {
  try {         
    IHTMLDocument2 document = IE.Document;
    object resp = document.parentWindow.execScript(script.ToString(), "JScript");
    Console.Write(resp);
  }
  catch (Exception) {
    throw;
  }
}
```

Minha variável **resp** sempre retorna **null**

A variável `script` pode receber qualquer comando JavaScript desde um simples `document.getElementById('id').value` até mesmo chamar uma função que eu tenha na página:

Digamos que eu tenha seguinte função na minha página:

```js
function soma(a,b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

E passe como parâmetro para minha função `wJScript("soma(1,2)")` ele deveria me retornar o resultado da função, mas isto não ocorre!

Comment: Você pode mandar o que a variável `script` contém?

Comment: @Danguilherme eu editei a pergunta... Mas esclarecendo, ela pode contem qualquer comando JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é o esperado deste método.

Conforme a [documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420(v=vs.85).aspx) o método `execScript` sempre retorna null

Veja um trecho:

> This method always returns null.

Que traduzido é:

> Esse método sempre retorna null

Answer (score 0):

Faz com teste com este trecho e vê se gera alguma `exception`

```
       try{
          IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)IE.Document;

            if (doc != null){
                IHTMLWindow2 parentWindow = doc.parentWindow;
                if (parentWindow != null)
                    parentWindow.execScript(script, "javascript");
             }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        }
```

Comment: Este tratamento só verificaria se o existe um `parentWindow` ou não, e não é esta a questão... eu consigo executar os scripts nas páginas, só que ele não me retorna nada.